# Match statement "NaN"

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, switch-statement

I am writing a python match/case statement that I want to apply to a pandas dataframe. But the data has a bunch of NaN values in it, and I can't figure out how to process them without them being handled in the default case `_`, because I want the default case to do something else

How can I match on NaN values ?

Here is an example code that I tried and doesn't work:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'col': ["foo", "a", "b", np.nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def handle_col(n):
    match n:
        case np.nan:
            return "not a number"
        case "a":
            return "this is letter a"
        case "b":
            return "this is letter b"
        case _:
            return "this is another string"
    
df["col"].apply(handle_col)
```

Here's the input dataframe

```
    col
0   foo
1   a
2   b
3   NaN
```

and the (wrong) answer I get:

```
0    this is another string
1          this is letter a
2          this is letter b
3    this is another string
Name: col, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that null values don't respect equality check i.e, `np.nan == np.nan` is `False`, the solution is to use guards in `case`:

```
def handle_col(n):
    match n:
        case _ if pd.isna(n):
            return "not a number"
        case "a":
            return "this is letter a"
        case "b":
            return "this is letter b"
        case _:
            return "this is another string"

df["col"].apply(handle_col)
```

---

```
0    this is another string
1          this is letter a
2          this is letter b
3              not a number
Name: col, dtype: object
```

Comment: TIL about guards in `case` statements. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, compare `number != number`:

```py
data = {'col': ["foo", "a", "b", np.nan, 1.4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def handle_col(n):
    match n:
        case float(n) if n != n:
            return "not a number"
        case float(n):
            return "a number"
        case "a":
            return "this is letter a"
        case "b":
            return "this is letter b"
        case _:
            return "this is another string"

print(df["col"].apply(handle_col))
```

Prints:

```
0    this is another string
1          this is letter a
2          this is letter b
3              not a number
4                  a number
Name: col, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a bit more complete handling floats that are not NaNs, but `n != n` is a bit confusing even though it works. I'll go with the other anwser.